# Как быстро разрешить конфликт в пользу LOCAL или REMOTE?

Tags: git

Подскажите, есть ведь быстрый способ разрешения конфликтов, если я точно знаю, что любые конфликты внутри файла нужно разрешать в пользу одной стороны, чтобы не тратить время протыкивая каждую строчку в `meld` и подобном ему инструментах?

Comment: Автоматическое разрешение конфликта в одну из сторон полностью отбрасывает изменения из другой. Зачем вообще нужен такой merge?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, бывает вот нужно. Коллеги тупят частенько. В идеальном мире может такого и нет, но некоторые патологически не способны нормально работать с git (и не только).

Comment: `git merge -s ort -Xours` не смотрели?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, "Use the given merge strategy; can be supplied more than once to specify them in the order they should be tried. If there is no -s option, a built-in list of strategies is used instead (ort when merging a single head, octopus otherwise)." Честно говоря, из этого мало что понятно.

Comment: Зачем вы привели эту цитату?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, спасибо, что подсказали. Я правда не могу ничего сказать по этому поводу. Нужно будет почитать на досуге про эти стратегии. Правда придётся специально создать конфликт для этого. Попробуем.

Comment: `git merge -s ours` или `git merge -s theirs`

Answer (score 0):

В общем, такого способа судя по всему нет, но можно просто пользоваться комбинацией:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Это лучше, чем протыкивать кажую коллизию мышью, особенно когда файлы большие и в них много изменений.

Comment: Ну и где предполагается эти кнопки нажимать-то? Хоть бы инструмент указали...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну так `meld` же. В вопросе указан.

Comment: В вопросе указано "meld и подобные", в подобие программ обычно не включается подобие хоткеев

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а в любом GUI так будет, разве что вы не используете Emacs или Vim =)